# While providing security all the tables goes into the "aspnetdb" database

Tags: asp.net, database, aspnetdb

I am developing a small website which contains admin pages, moderator pages and user pages.  I have provided the security using `asp.net` configuration and I followed all the six steps.

The problem is after providing the security all tables are saved in the `aspnetdb` database, but I want all these tables into my own database.

Does any know how to save all the tables into my own database?  If possible, give me some examples with more explanation.

Note: I am using a client system and the database is presented in the server system.

Comment: You might be better off putting your personal details on your profile page.

Answer (score 1):

In your web.config, there should be a setting within the `<connectionStrings>` section. I think the default is maybe just `ApplicationConnection`

This will be pointing to a SQLServer Express database file, so you can update this to your own database connection.

Then if you look for the sections `<membership defaultProvider="SqlProvider">` `<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="SqlProvider">` you will see a setting within each for `connectionStringName` this will be pointing to the connection string. Make sure that this is the same as the connection string which is pointing to your database.

You database is probably lacking the tables for the asp.net security, so you will want to look into generating these.

[aspnet_regsql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x28wfk74.aspx) is what you want to look into. This auto generates all the tables needed, then the first time your application is running, it adds some details to the tables, e.g. application name, id, etc...